# What happens when disabling maintenance of unread marks?

Tags: database, lotus-notes, read-unread

We have several Lotus Notes databases that are by default has their unread marks maintained. We disabled this maintenance to speed up the application. When we disable the unread marks, is it deleted in the database? I learned that the unread marks are stored in the database itself. Also what will happen if we re-enable it, will it show the same number of unread marks before we disable it or will start anew?

Answer (score 1):

Unread marks are stored within each replica in a table and whenever you enable it, it starts out empty. I would imagine that when you disable it, it gets deleted, but am uncertain if that is immediate or not. A good Q&A can be found [this document on IBM's support site](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27023614).